# how to remove exact match of words in data frame in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose the following data frame with one column called < game >:

```
df:
   game
0  juegos blue
1  juego red
2  juegos yellow
```

I would like to remove the words from the following list of stop words:

```
stopWords = ['juego','juegos']
```

and the desired result is:

```
df:
   game
0  blue
1  red
2  yellow
```

I tried that:

```
df['game'] = df['game'].str.replace("|".join(stopWords ), " ")
```

The function works but it removes 'juego' from the entry "juegos" leaving an 's' alone:

```
df:
   game
0  s blue
1   red
2  s yellow
```

Is there a way to remove words only if there is an exact match?

Comment: in regex you can specify that a match is only a match if the word you are searching for is followed by whitespce (you can use the \s symbol to specify whitespace). You are currently not using direct regex so this method will not work, but if you change your code a bit it is possible

Comment: Can't you go with `df['game'] = df['game'].str.replace(r'\bjuegos?\b\s*', "", regex=True)`, or the likes.

Comment: @JvdV thanks! It could work but the stop word list is actually much longer than that, so is the data frame I am working on

Comment: Oke well then why not: `df['game'] = df['game'].str.replace(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(stopWords) + ')\b\s*, '', regex=True)`. Does that help? Currently the `s` stays in place because you haven't used boundaries and the nature of regex is to match from left to right. If you would concatenate your words from longest to shortest it would have worked but saver are word-boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it with pandas DataFrame.replace()

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'game': ['juegos blue', 'juego red', 'juegos yellow']}) 
   ...: stop_words = [r'juego\b', r'juegos\b'] 
   ...: df.replace(to_replace={'game': '|'.join(stop_words)}, value='', regex=True, inplace=True) 
   ...: df                                                                                                                                                    
Out[1]: 
      game
0     blue
1      red
2   yellow

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'game': ['juegos blue', 'juego red', 'juegos yellow']}) 
   ...: stop_words = [r'juego\b'] 
   ...: df.replace(to_replace={'game': '|'.join(stop_words)}, value='', regex=True, inplace=True) 
   ...: df                                                                                                                                                    
Out[2]: 
            game
0    juegos blue
1            red
2  juegos yellow
```

Assuming that stop 'words' end with the word boundary `\b`.

Comment: This still leaves "s" if he only searches for `'juego'` instead of `'juegos?'` (`?` makes last character optional, which functionally searches both `'juego'` and `'juegos'`). But you could add `([.,\s]|$)` or something to the end of search term to search for complete words.

Comment: It also leaves the string with a space in front like `' red'`.

Comment: I think that would be the expected result? If `'juego'` is the only stop word then I would understand it to mean the `s` should not be removed.

Comment: I'll edit to add the stop words as a separate list so they are matched exactly.

Comment: "Is there a way to remove words only if there is an exact match?" probably means to not do anything if it doesn't match exactly, so if `stopWords = ['juego']`, don't change `'juegos blue'` to `'s blue'`

Comment: Got it, I wasn't thinking "word", just looked for a match.

Comment: @purpin thank you for your help. The remove list contains actually a list of hundreds of words. For the sake of simplicity I have reduced it to two words. Joseph is right: if  `stopWords = ['juego']`, don't change `'juegos blue'` to  `'s blue'`. However if  `stopWords = ['juego','juegos']` change to  `' blue'`

Comment: @Makth Interesting. You *do* want the extra space before "blue"? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I have edited it to address @JosephHansen 's point. I hope this is what you need Makth?

Comment: @JosephHansen well, it does not matter. I think I can trim spaces separately if the word to be removed is included in a group of words such as in `two juegos blue`

Comment: @purpin yes, thank you! It works very well. My next step is to construct/reformat the giant remove list following your example. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Python string replace won't work, but the regex module will. You're going to need to add some markup to the string to make the regex look for complete words. For instance, maybe you know it's a complete word because it's followed by a period `.`, comma `,`, or whitespace of any type `\s`, or an endline `$`. `\b` is the regex pattern for word boundaries.

```
import re
s1 = df['game'].str
for sw in stopWords:
    s1 = re.sub(r'{0}\b'.format(sw), '', s1)
df['game'].str = s1
```

(I stole the `\b` from [this other good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079574/756329).)

---

Keeping old code in case you're interested. This one also removes whitespace, comma, or period directly after the matching word, which is not what you asked for but might be useful.

```
import re
s1 = df['game'].str
for sw in stopWords:
    s1 = re.sub(r'{0}([.,\s]|$)'.format(sw), '', s1)
df['game'].str = s1
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help! Trying your code resulted is an error, but I'll dig into it. The data frame does not necessarily have a period, comma, or whitespace after the word to be removed if this one is the last word within the cell. Now that I type I realize there is a space before or after the word

Comment: thanks for your second code. I'll try to understand the reason why I'm getting an error

Comment: @Makth You should click the checkmark next to an answer once you've found one that works for you or one you prefer. Looks like the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079574/756329) is working for you.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm very grateful for your recommendations and support! Cheers!